# Hochschild cohomology of a boolean ring

Tags: ring-theory, reference-request, homological-algebra, boolean-algebra, hochschild-cohomology

I can’t find any papers studying the Hochschild cohomology ring $H^*(B, B)$, where $B$ is a boolean ring, so I was wondering if this is known.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know?  If $B$ is finite then it's trivial (because $B\otimes B$ is semisimple); if $B$ is infinite then I would expect everything to be horribly infinite and hard to describe nicely, but maybe it's nicer than I expect.

Comment: Good point. I should have said that I am interesred in the non-separable case.